# Publishing is currently not possible for project 'xxxxx'.? - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator, qml

I'm currently on Ubuntu 13.04, I've just finished setting up Qt Creator and had just made a new HTML UI app. It says the target is "Desktop" and I can run the app no problem from within the IDE.

[image]

The problem occurs when I try to publish the app or in other words, get it to some form that is distributable. I get the following error:

[image]

What can be possibly wrong here? As I said, I can run the app without problems within the IDE.